# Elegant workaround for Safari print without print dialog bug?

Tags: printing, applescript, safari

The AppleScript standard suite has a command that will print from an application, allowing for the specifying of certain options and printing without displaying a dialog box. For example:

```
tell application "Safari"
    print document 1 with properties {copies:3} without print dialog
end tell
```

However, there appears to be a bug in the current version of Safari that prevents this from happening like it's supposed to.<sup>1</sup> When specifying `without print dialog`, a sheet pops up in the window that should display progress in processing the print job, but instead of doing so it just hangs with a nondescriptive barberpole.

In trying to work around this, I realize that if I specify `with print dialog`, everything works as it's supposed to. The script pauses execution on that line after displaying the dialog, and then continues after the user has hit the print button in the dialog. The most elegant workaround for this would be to `keystroke return` after the dialog is shown, but I don't think this is possible given that the script is paused on that line until the dialog is dismissed.

A much less elegant workaround is this:

```
on printCopiesOfCurrentPage(copies)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Safari"
            keystroke "p" using command down
            keystroke copies as text
            keystroke return
            delay 3
        end tell
    tell
end printCopiesOfCurrentPage
```

Since there's no way to delay execution until the print job is sent off, we have to guess with a `delay 3`, which is either going to be inefficient or problematic.

Any other possibilities here? Maybe a way to watch for the print dialog disappearing after using the keystroke method, or a way to kick off the job after `print with dialog` is invoked?

---

<sup>1. The first time I tried this, it actually printed one and a half pages before kind of flipping out and causing a printer jam, of all things. I haven't been able to replicate it since, so if someone could confirm this bug for me, it would be appreciated.</sup>